# How to have Google maps search bar sit in a semi-transparent full width div

Tags: javascript, css, api, google-maps, maps

I am stumped. I need to have the search bar sitting in a semi transparent div at the top of the map. I have tried every combination of nesting, not nesting, z-index, and no matter what the search bar sits under the div but I can't click it and it's only visible because the div is transparent...

The issue is with the div I've called class="nav"

```js
function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: {lat: 43.6615, lng: -70.2553},
     zoom: 15
   });

   var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

   var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
   autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(input);

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
   infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map
   });
   marker.addListener('click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
   });

   autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
     infowindow.close();
     var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
     if (!place.geometry) {
       return;
     }

     if (place.geometry.viewport) {
       map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
     } else {
       map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
       map.setZoom(15);
     }

     // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
     marker.setPlace({
       placeId: place.place_id,
       location: place.geometry.location
     });
     marker.setVisible(true);

     infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
     infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
     infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = place.formatted_address;
     infowindow.open(map, marker);
   });
 }
```

```css
#map {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .6;
  z-index: 2;
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 29px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-right: 17px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.controls:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
  z-index: 10;
}
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}
#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" width="device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>iBec Map Project</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Aurora Provisions">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <div id="infowindow-content">
    <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
       Place ID <span id="place-id"></span><br>
    <span id="place-address"></span>
  </div>

    <script src="project.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDu3PmYIdOr0EebzqQL2sGQCjrKaUzkONg&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line:

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(input);
```

That is removing the autocomplete input element and adding it to the map (so it is under the "nav" div).

You will then need to adjust its placement (or the placement of the map type controls) to remove the overlap.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fLyem5s9/)

**code snippet:**

```css
#map {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .6;
  z-index: 2;
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 29px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-right: 17px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.controls:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
  z-index: 10;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<title>iBec Map Project</title>

<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Aurora Provisions">
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="nav"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br> Place ID <span id="place-id"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: 43.6615,
        lng: -70.2553
      },
      zoom: 15
    });

    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    //   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(input);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        return;
      }

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(15);
      }

      // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
      marker.setPlace({
        placeId: place.place_id,
        location: place.geometry.location
      });
      marker.setVisible(true);

      infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
      infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
      infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = place.formatted_address;
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: This is a big help - I am still struggling to get the search bar to and overlay to sit over the map but that was definitely the problem. I also don't completely understand how the information is being pushed without that line but I will spend some time trying to understand the black magic of it.  Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.